# Is it possible to consume external ASP.NET WEB API's from SAP CRM?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, sap-crm

My API's are working fine, now I want them as an open API. To consume those API from SAP CRM? Because there is need to do somehow handshake configuration things to call API from SAP. But, I don't know how to do this. Does anyone had worked on such requirement?